# Can I change output midi device of mciSendString

Tags: c#, midi, mci

So I finally found one of the posts that helped me out on this class

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.IO;

namespace MidiProgram
{
/// <summary>
/// MCIPlayer is based off code by Slain.
/// Found here: http://www.sadeveloper.net/Articles_View.aspx?articleID=212
/// </summary>
public class MCIPlayer
{

    private static readonly string sAlias = "TeaTimerAudio";

    [DllImport("winmm.dll")]
    private static extern long mciSendString(string strCommand, StringBuilder strReturn, int iReturnLength, IntPtr hwndCallback);
    [DllImport("Winmm.dll")]
    private static extern long PlaySound(byte[] data, IntPtr hMod, UInt32 dwFlags);

    public static void Play(string sFile)
    {
        _Open(sFile);
        _Play();
    }
    public static void Stop()
    {
        _Close();
    }

    private static void _Open(string sFileName)
    {
        if (_Status() != "")
            _Close();

        string sCommand = "open \"" + sFileName + "\" alias " + sAlias;
        mciSendString(sCommand, null, 0, IntPtr.Zero);
    }

    private static void _Close()
    {
        string sCommand = "close " + sAlias;
        mciSendString(sCommand, null, 0, IntPtr.Zero);
    }

    private static void _Play()
    {
        string sCommand = "play " + sAlias;
        mciSendString(sCommand, null, 0, IntPtr.Zero);
    }

    private static string _Status()
    {
        StringBuilder sBuffer = new StringBuilder(128);
        mciSendString("status " + sAlias + " mode", sBuffer, sBuffer.Capacity, IntPtr.Zero);
        return sBuffer.ToString();
    }
}
}
```

however I seem to find a little bit if a problem, the whole program makes a 
sound but apparently it outputs to (microsoft gs wavetable synth)
is there a way inside this class that I can change how the midi outputs to or is it just playing just like MediaPlayer in that form, please tell me, this is the last move to my project just a simple code, and lets just say I can do it can I specify the midi device by an integer or by its name, by integer I mean the midi devices order!

Answer (score 0):

The MCI sequencer device allows you to set the port with the [set command](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd798661.aspx):

> set port *port_number*

Comment: What do you mean, I've seen a specific post on microsoft that you can do it in visual basic, I suppose you can do it in C# too